# Protractor for Angular E2E Testing: What is the best approach to manage test data?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ui-automation

I am new to `Angular` and `Protractor`. I have written couple of protractor test cases to automate registration, login and some other pages. To execute a test case for example student registration, I need to pass some data like name,dob,age,address etc, right now I hardcoded those values in my test cases which is not best practice so I want to externalize these input data values for all my protractor test cases. I have below thoughts around this but not able to decide which one is the best approach and industry standard.

1. Keep input data in `JSON` file for each test set separately.
2. Keep all test sets input data in single `JSON` file.
3. Keep the test data in .js file read it from there.

please suggest me the best approach and any other best practices I should consider while writing protractor UI test cases as I am completely new to this framework.I am using protractor with `jasmine 2.x`.

-Amar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The data can be read from JSON file.

Step 1: Create a JSON file and add it into your project folder

`{
    "UserName":"uname@blah.com",
    "Password":"blahblah",
}`

Step 2: Import the file into your protractor.conf.js and assign it to params

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    params: require('./testdata.json'),
```

Step 3: Access data in your test cases by referring the key values using ‘browser.params’ object

```
element(by.css('input[type=email]')).sendKeys(browser.params.UserName);
```

refer my blog for more information
[Data Driven Testing in Protractor Frameworks](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/10/data-driven-testing-in-protractor-webdriverjs-frameworks-reading-data-from-an-external-json-file/)

[POM Design Pattern in Protractor Frameworks](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/11/page-object-modelpom-page-object-design-pattern-in-protractor-webdriverjs-nodejs-automation-frameworks/)

[Configuring Explicit Waits in protractor E2E Framework - Best Practices](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/30/configuring-explicit-waits-in-protractor-e2e-test-frameworks/)

Comment: Thank you Aditya for your quick answers. I will go throw them once and let you know.