# How to write protractor e2e test cases when front end is dependent on the data returned by REST Api (backend)?

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I have REST api which returns list of students and I display that list on UI in the form of cards. I want to test this functionality from protractor e2e.

Is there any way to mock backend and test the front end from protractor?
Also, why can't we use component's functionality for testing? (only have access to Page object from protractor)

PS : I am using Angular 4

Comment: They have some solid cases on the intro website: https://angular.io/guide/testing. General idea is to create mock data to test the component (and test that any http service gets called) and test the service independently to make sure it functions as intended.

Comment: According to the [Protractor Style-Guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#dont-mock-unless-you-need-to): "Don't mock unless you need to". What exactly do you want to test? The appearance of all fields of one card? the correct amount of cards? The name of the students (if so, don't you have control over your test data)? Further check best-practices, like [this one](https://github.com/CarmenPopoviciu/protractor-styleguide), [this one](https://github.com/bolshchikov-public/protractor-best-practices) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39263652/8683679)

Comment: @ErnstZwingli Thanks a lot. That was really helpful. I have created the test.json and now able to test some functionality.

However, I am facing difficulty in setting value of repeater.
I display list using *ngFor="let student of getStudents()". Is there any way to set this repeater through protractor. I tried following, but I am not getting the student list...

element(by.binding('getStudents()')).sendKeys(browser.params);
        return element.all(by.repeater('let student of getStudents()'));